# Zend_Date : expanding a 2 digit year value to 4 digit year

Tags: zend-framework

Have a date of birth in format 'MM/dd/yy' for people born in the 1900's. I'm using Zend_Date to 
parse and convert the string value

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
$logger->info(sprintf('Convert DOB %s -> %s',$dateOfBirth,$date->toString('yyyy-M-dd')));
```

I get

```
2010-06-24T16:55:50+00:00 INFO (6): DOB 9/13/57
2010-06-24T16:55:50+00:00 INFO (6): Convert DOB : 9/13/57 -> 2057-9-13
```

I expected

```
2010-06-24T16:55:50+00:00 INFO (6): Convert 9/13/57 -> 1957-9-13
```

What am i missing? I don't think this is related to the real year 'yyyy' / ISO year 'YYYY' handling in Zend_Date.

My current horrible hack

```
$formattedDate = $date->toString('dd/M').'/19'.$date->toString('YY');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short (1 or 2 digit) version of YEAR is always in current century.
so use:

```
    $dob = '9/13/57';
    $date = new Zend_Date($dob, 'M/d/yy');
    echo $date->subYear(100)->toString('YYYY-MM-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's a bit more complicated. According to [this site](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Date/Zend_Date_DateObject/Zend_Date.html), 2-digit years greater than or equal to 70 become 1970-1999 whereas those less than 70 become 2000-2069.